# bash test - match forward slashes

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression

I have a git branch name:

```
current_branch='oleg/feature/1535693040'
```

I want to test if the branch name includes /feature/, so I use:

```
if [ "$current_branch" != */feature/* ] ; then
  echo "Current branch does not seem to be a feature branch by name, please check, and use --force to override.";
  exit 1;
fi
```

but that branch name doesn't match the regex, so I am exiting with 1, anyone know why?

Comment: Isn’t =~ the regex operator?

Comment: That also looks more like a glob pattern than a regex.

Comment: yeah I think I mean "patterns" not "regex", will remove the tag

Comment: I got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123576/bash-test-match-forward-slashes/52123622

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123576/bash-test-match-forward-slashes/52123622

the answer is:

`[ ]` is the single-bracket [`test(1)` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test), which does not handle patterns the same way bash does.  Instead, use the double-bracket [bash conditional expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) `[[ ]]`.  Example:

```
$ current_branch='oleg/feature/1535693040'
$ [ "$current_branch" = '*/feature/*' ] && echo yes
$ [[ $current_branch = */feature/* ]] && echo yes
yes
```

**Edit** with regexes:

```
$ [[ $current_branch =~ /feature/ ]] && echo yes
yes
```

The regex can match anywhere, so you don't need the leading and trailing `*` (which would be `.*` in a regex).

CAUTION: the slashes here are not delimiters for the regex, but literals to be matched somewhere in the string.  For example, `[[ foo/bar =~ / ]]` returns true.  This is different from regex notation in many languages.